# Upload PDF/Word File code for Android

Tags: android, pdf, file-upload

I am working on a mobile app. There's provision for the user to upload his CV. So basically once the user clicks on a button he should see the file browser then select the file and upload it to the server.

If anyone can provide me with some sample code that would be helpful. I can provide more information if my question doesn't sound specific enough.

Comment: I don't know how this question can be answered without just doing it for you. Have you tried anything yourself? 
Show your effort and explain what specifically did not work with your code. As is, it appears that you are just asking us to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

[Send a request for the file](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/request-file.html)

This article has sample code about what you ask for. Basically you need to specify a MIME type for document you want. In the sample this type is jpg but you need to use application/pdf. At the end you are interested with the result and onActivityResult should overriden on the directory of your needs.

There is not much information about your problem, hope it helps.